# IE8 Side By Side DIVS are stacking

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-8

I have read all the SO questions I can find already and have been at this for 4 days now (sadly). Please do not think that I am trying to shortcut some work by posting it here. I would be happy to read about a solution and apply it myself but chances are I've already tried it...

Please view [this page](http://www.aesyliften.nl/test-page) in **IE8**

As you can see, the left side menu drops below the page content. This is the only page on the site that does this. I thought it was something in the CSS that I added specific to that page, but in removing the custom CSS entirely, not only did the page look like crap, but it didn't fix the left side menu.

If anyone could advise me on how to get the left menu actually on the left side, I would be very appreciative.

**UPDATE (incredibly embarrassing)**
I had a div in the right side of page that didn't have a closing tag. It caused the left menu to be a child of the right content which explained the display behavior.

I sincerely apologize for wasting the time of those who have read this question and especially those who took their time to view the page and offer advice.

Comment: Seems like floating and width issue to me

Answer (score 1):

it seems that `float: right` isn't set on your right div

also right div has left margins, which prevents left div to be where it is supposed to be

```
#content {
    float: right !important;
    margin-left: 0 !important;
}
```

Comment: Because of this comment, I actually noticed that the divs are misplaced in the markup. The "left" div is actually INSIDE the "right" div (as a parent-child); they are not element siblings as they should be.

Comment: Please answer your own question if you feel like you've solved your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have IE8 but have you tried adding

```
display: inline;
```

or

```
display: inline-block;
```

to `#primary` and `#secondary`?

Let me know if this doesn't work, I'll have access to a computer with IE8 later today.

Comment: If you have IE9, just set it to compatibility mode and it does the same thing.

Comment: Compatibility mode in IE 9 is terrible. Use the actual browsers if possible. Run a VM if you can with them on.

Comment: I disagree that `browser mode` in IE9 is terrible. It works fine almost always. But only sometimes with some complicated markup it may not display all issues